# jquery TypeError: Response is null

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, linux, apache

Code below returns JavaScript error : *TypeError: Response is null*

Note: it works fine on my local machine WAMP but fails on live LINUX host.

Any ideas?

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#run").click(function(event)
   {
      $('#run').hide();
      $('#loader').fadeIn(1000);

      $.ajax(
      {
         type       : 'POST',
         url        : 'process.php',
         data       : 'name=jolly&surname=fish',
         dataType   : 'json',
         success    : function(response)
         {
             $('#loader').stop(true).fadeOut(function ()
             {
                  if (response.status == 'goodjob')
                  {
                      $('#tick').fadeIn(1000, function ()
                      {
                          $('#script').fadeIn(1000);
                      });
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      $('#cross').fadeIn(1000);
                  }
              });
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
          {
              alert(textStatus + '---' + errorThrown);
          }
      });
   });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="first">
   <img id="run" src="run.png" />
   <img id="loader" src="loader.png" style="display:none;" />
   <img id="success" src="success.png" style="display:none;" />
   <img id="fail" src="fail.png" style="display:none;" />
</div>
<div id="next" style="display:none;">
   ....
   ....
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php echo json_encode(array('status' => 'goodjob')); ?>
```

**DETAILS FROM FIREBUG**

--- HEADERS

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Thu, 30 Aug 2012 13:33:41 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Proxy-Connection    Keep-Alive
Server  Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.1.6

Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Content-Length  27
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  MoodleSession=7uck9j6n2ff7r9vc63tvt85t43; MoodleSessionTest=q0Ywtc2psj; MOODLEID_=%25E2%25C8%2513E%25BD
Host    192.168.10.11
Pragma  no-cache
Proxy-Connection    keep-alive
Referer http://192.168.10.11/portal/update-database/index.php
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

--- POST

```
Parameters application/x-www-form-urlencoded
name jolly
surname fish

Source
name=jolly&surname=fish
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle? It would help us solve this faster.

Comment: try saving your response from php in a simple variable

Comment: $status='goodjob'; echo $status

Comment: in JQuery success function check like this 
success    : function(response)
         {
           if (response == 'goodjob'){}

Comment: json support in phpinfo() is not listed as I guess that's the problem. It is enabled in my local php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your php file return

```
$status = 'goodjob';
echo $status;
```

In your Jquery

```
success    : function(response)
{
   if(response == 'goodjob')
   //what you want todo
}
```

Comment: actually it would be `if (response.status=='goodjob')`. see the question for details

Comment: sorry you are right, i misread your question. if it was an array('status'=>'goodjob') as in the question then it should be response.status but your example is right. sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be js related if it works on your local wamp. You need to check up on your live host.

Make sure that the server is able to run php.

Make sure you don't need

Check any error logs on the server - anything that prevents the script from running could cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

firstly, test your PHP file yourself by hitting the URL with a browser, and pasting the output to the JSON linter here: http://jsonlint.com/

I have had an issue before where my live PHP server had different error settings than my local one, so sometimes AJAX calls would fail because the output would get polluted by error messages from PHP and fail to validate as JSON.

Second, TEST YOUR RESPONSE! 
In the callback for your `$.ajax()` call, you just plunge right in and assume that `response` has a value. Never assume that a variable you didn't define yourself has a value, especially in javascript.
A simple test like:

`if (response)` or `if (typeof(response)!=='undefined'` will save you headaches.